# Upload image to server Ios.I have uiimageview and want to send imageview image to server for objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, image

I am trying to take picture and send to data base (`json` using `post` `method`) in ios

```
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender
{
   // NSData *imageData = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;      
   // UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image,0.8);
   NSString *urlString = [ NSString     stringWithFormat:@"https://www.******/xyz/jsonurl.php?action=insert&lat=80.2626&long=29.64565&cat=1&note=&date=&sdkuserid=12345&nick_name=sandy&place_address=pluto&p_id=3&intid=%d,&name=userfile&filename=%@",1,imageData];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
   [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

   NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

   NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
   [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

   NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%d\"\r\n", 1]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [request setHTTPBody:body];
   NSLog(@"   body   %@",body);

   [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Trying to upload image to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code  and give me response

```
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender 
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image,0.8);
    NSString *urlString = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.******/xyz/jsonurl.php?action=insert&lat=80.2626&long=29.64565&cat=1&note=&date=&sdkuserid=12345&nick_name=sandy&place_address=pluto&p_id=3&intid=1"];
    urlString =[[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Urlstr]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
     NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd_hhmmss"];        
    NSString * fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"New%@.png\"\r\n",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

     NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
     NSString *ImageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Comment: If u like my answer so please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: Well I copy paste your text and changed the sdkuserid=12345     and    www.******/xyz    only. But data base is not updating.Do i have to do anything else

Comment: what will you send on this attribute name=userfile?

Comment: That is static well can you suggest me,do I have to add this to my url

Comment: Please explain your url paramter because i don't understand what is you pass in paramaeters. image upload code is ready only change your url.

Comment: there will be lattitude,longitude,user id,date and image....this will go to server anf userfile is name of the folder in database

Comment: What is pass in name parameter image or other value?

Comment: Well ,i dont have such parameter,I am bit confused.I didnot get any extra parameter for image.I was told to add those in para meter---name=\"filename\"; filename=\"\"\r\n"

One more thing,What will go in parameter ,,like image name  or some code as i got like <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 0   .... like this

Comment: Now don't changed. i have changed your parameter in my code

Comment: only remove ,&name=userfile contain in your url

Comment: filename is the parameter for my image sorry

place_address=pluto&p_id=3&intid=%dfilename=",1];

this is what i have done now

 NSLog(@"----- >  %@",ImageString);
  it is empty

Comment: ok don't worry i have put in my code you just remove ,&name=userfile contain in your url and check

Comment: yes I have ...
action=insert&lat=90.2626&long=89.23123&cat=1&note=&date=&sdkuserid=12345&nick_name=sandy&place_address=pluto&p_id=3&intid=%d",1];   


This what I have done and looks like.rest all same and yes.instead of png,i have changed it to jpg

Comment: yes your url is right and replace first line NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageview.image);

Comment: Please send me your code so i will review your code sandeep

Comment: what happen sandeep Working or not?

Comment: My code is longer than the words support here

u have ur email id ?

Comment: can you send only .m file in my mail id suvagiyarohit@gmail.com

Comment: I have send you just now

Comment: all except image is uploading

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
-(void)uploadImageOnServer:(NSData *)imageData forId:(NSString *)imageId
{
        NSURL *strURL = myUrl; //here is your url

        // setting up the request object now
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
        [request setURL:strURL];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------147378098314876653456641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        /*
         now lets create the body of the post
        */

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Documents\"; filename=\%@.png\r\n",imageId];
        [body appendData: [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
}
```

Here 'Documents' is your folder name where you want to save this image to your backend server. Hope this helps you.... Enjoy!

Comment: what do I have to do here 
/*
         now lets create the body of the post
 */

Comment: You dont have to do anything over here, this is only for pragma instruction.. just copy and paste this above code and check in your backend. imageId is just an unique name like reference of your image.

Comment: If call this function  inside the action button,what parameter i need to pass

Comment: call this fuction as [self uploadImageOnServer:myImageData forId:myImageName];  // here myImageData is your NSData and myImageName is your image reference name. :)

Comment: I did that too in my action button

Comment: then whats the problem.. its not uploading ??

Comment: Yes...all except image